# Activities involved in recreating SharePoint Site Collections

Tags: 2010, site-collection

When researching SharePoint  solutions online, I occasionally see a suggestion to simply recreate a site collection, rather than attempt complicated in-depth troubleshooting.  Can anyone please advise what actual activities would be required to recreate a site collection, assuming the site is somewhat large and complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Site template

One of the OOTB ways may be to use a [site template](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Create-and-use-site-templates-60371b0f-00e0-4c49-a844-34759ebdd989), but your requirement states that the site is large and complex whereas site template has 50MB limit and "customized permissions, running workflow instances, list item version history, workflow tasks associated with running workflows, people or group field values, taxonomy field values, publishing sites and pages, and stapled features" are all unsupported.

2. Content and structure

Within **one** site collection you can use [content and structure](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Work-with-site-content-and-structure-30fcaad9-02b1-4347-8b03-e1ccc5a4c19f) feature and use it move some or all items or even entire subsites. [How to guide](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/07/29/how-to-use-the-site-content-and-structure-manager-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

3. ShareGate

A very popular migration tool. It offers full site migration or moving entire site collections and many other [migration options](http://en.share-gate.com/sharepoint-migration). You can try them for free [here](http://en.share-gate.com/sharepoint-migration).

Comment: Thanks grisha.  Just one question - supposing the original Site Collection has some technical issues that cause it to not work correctly (for example, missing out-of-the-box content types that can't be restored), which of the above suggestions would allow a site to be recreated correctly, but without any internal errors that may have infested the original?

Comment: I'd say content and structure and -maybe- ShareGate (ask their support for details). With the template you will recreate a site exactly as it was so the types may still be missing (for me it fixed some issues with workflows though). With content and structure you are moving items so the settings are refreshed.

Comment: Thanks grisha, I've accepted your answer as I believe it has led me on the correct path.  Just as an extra follow up question - would it make sense to backup and restore the sites (content export) from the faulty site collection to a new site collection?

Comment: It depends on what the fault is. If it is a missing site COLLECTION feature then yes.